Webcomic about a monster girl bar
I'm looking for a webcomic about a monster girl bar, but forgot its name. It takes place in a world where monsters and magic are real and regular things.
The story starts with a siren girl (NOT mermaid), who has bird like clawed hands and feet, short red/brunette hair, and long buck teeth. There is even a joke that someone calls her a chipmunk and she uses her siren song to make them punch themselves.
She is a pole dancer at the bar and one day she sees a homeless blonde girl and helps her out. They became friends, roommates and colleagues, because the blonde girl got a job in the bar. We later finds out that the blonde girl started out as a guy. Since one of their ancestors was a siren, their figure became feminine and they grew breasts, but they still remained "fully functional" down there. Because of that they ran away from home and finds shelter in the bar.
The monster girl bar has many other unique employees who mostly live on the second floor. The bartender is a gargoyle woman with a medusa girlfriend. The bouncer is a "jotunn", a big, literally fiery, hot demon-looking guy, and the blonde girl has a crush on him. There is also a guy in mask who is a "half-doppelganger," he just only can turn into a big, tall lady and he is also a pole dancer in the bar. And the owner is a beautiful and powerful sorcerer woman who is some old Aztec god or something.
Siren "chipmunk" girl's dad is a human with an eye patch, and he is a member of some special police force to keep monster people safe. His partner is a dark skinned girl with mechanical limbs. They rescued a nymph girl that was drugged by kidnappers. And later they asks help from the magic lady of the monster girl bar.
I think the monster girl bar's name is the name of the webcomic. I think I read it on Webtoon or Tapas or other easily available website. I don't really remember anything else, just that the webcomic is still ongoing.

Interesting. Based on the title of the question I was fully prepared to hop in and be able to tell you it was a comic called Crittertongue, but this appears to be something of a two nickles situation.

Thankfully, someone found it for me.
Mythed Up

"In a modern world where the barriers between the Supernatural and Natural vanished hundreds of years ago, seeing a centaur working as a personal trainer and a harpy running a courier service isn't out of the ordinary. Though, as in any version of our world, people are still people."

